# git-svn: replacing trunk branch with another

Tags: svn, git, branch, git-svn, trunk

How to replace the trunk branch with another in svn repository using git-svn tool?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Are you trying to check out another branch or actually change what master points to and tracks?

Comment: like svn actions like: svn mv trunk oldtrank && svn mv dev trunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not something git-svn can do; while you can rename your branches on the git side, or tell your git clone's master to track a branch other than trunk, you'll need to use SVN to do the SVn branch rename.

Comment: In fact it doesn't matter case our svn repository has been fully converted to git ;) Thanks for participate!